# having trouble with Flutter null safety, database object refuses to initialize

Tags: flutter, null

I have been trying to implement a simple To Do app without providers (for the course's sake) to advance in the course at the pace the instructor intended. But I cannot seem to find a solution for this small problem..
in the below code, the variable  `database` does not want to be initialized whatsoever. The `getData()` method that's supposed to retrieve data (query) doesn't initialize the variable `database` even if I call it in `createDatabase()` in `initState()` It keeps giving the following errors:

''' I/flutter ( 5171): error LateInitializationError: Field 'database' has not been initialized. during open, closing...
E/flutter ( 5171): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: LateInitializationError: Field 'database' has not been initialized.
'''

````
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:to_do_app/modules/todo_app/archived/archived_screen.dart';
import 'package:to_do_app/modules/todo_app/done/done_screen.dart';
import 'package:to_do_app/modules/todo_app/tasks/tasks_screen.dart';

class HomeLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeLayout({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeLayout> createState() => _HomeLayoutState();
}
class _HomeLayoutState extends State<HomeLayout> {

  int currentIndex = 0;
  

  List<String> titles = [
    'Tasks',
    'Done Tasks',
    'Archived Tasks',
  ];

  List<Map> tasks = [];
  late Database database;
  var scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  bool isOpen = false;
  IconData fabIcon = Icons.edit;
  var titleController = TextEditingController();
  var dateController = TextEditingController();
  var timeController = TextEditingController();
  var formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  void initState()  {
    super.initState();
    createDatabase();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List <Widget> screens = [
    NewTasksScreen(),
    DoneTasksScreen(),
    ArchivedTasksScreen()
  ];
  
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(titles[currentIndex]),
      ),

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: ()  {
          if(isOpen == false){
            isOpen = true;
            setState(() {
              fabIcon = Icons.add;
            });
            scaffoldKey.currentState!.showBottomSheet(
              (context) => SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: Form(
                    key: formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        TextFormField(
                          validator: (value){
                            if(value!.isEmpty){
                              return 'title must not be empty';
                            }
                          },
                          controller: titleController,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Title',
                            prefixIcon: Icon(
                              Icons.title
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                        TextFormField(
                          onTap: (){
                            showDatePicker(
                              context: context, 
                              initialDate: DateTime.now(), 
                              firstDate: DateTime.now(), 
                              lastDate: DateTime(2025)
                            ).then((value) {
                              dateController.text =  DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(value!);
                            });
                          },
                           validator: (value){
                            if(value!.isEmpty){
                              return 'date must not be empty';
                            }
                          },
                          controller: dateController,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Date',
                            prefixIcon: Icon(
                              Icons.date_range
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                        TextFormField(
                          onTap: (){
                            showTimePicker(
                              context: context, 
                              initialTime: TimeOfDay.now()
                            ).then((value) {
                              timeController.text = value!.format(context);
                            });
                          },
                           validator: (value){
                            if(value!.isEmpty){
                              return 'time must not be empty';
                            }
                          },
                          controller: timeController,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Time',
                            prefixIcon: Icon(
                              Icons.timer
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ).closed.then(
              (value) {
                isOpen = false;
              }
            );
          } else {
            if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
              insertIntoDatabase(
                title: titleController.text,
                date: dateController.text,
                time: timeController.text
              ).then((value) {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                isOpen = false;
                setState(() {
                  fabIcon = Icons.edit;
                });
              });
            }
            
          }
        },
        child: Icon(
          fabIcon
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        elevation: 20,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.task_alt
            ),
            label: 'new tasks'
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.done
            ),
            label: 'done tasks'
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.archive_outlined
            ),
            label: 'archived tasks'
          )
        ],
        onTap: (index){
          setState(() {
            currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
      ),
      body: screens[currentIndex],
    );
  }

  Future getName() async {
    return 'Ahmad Ali';
  }
  
   void createDatabase() async {
    database = await openDatabase(
      'todo.db',
      version: 1,
      onCreate: (database, version)  {
        print('databse created');
         database.execute(
          'CREATE TABLE tasks(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT, date TEXT, time TEXT, status TEXT)'
        ).then(
          (value) {
            print('table created');
          }
        ).catchError(
          (error){
            print('error creating table ${error.toString()}');
          }
        );
      },
      onOpen: (databse)  async {
        print('database opened');
        await getData(database).then((value) {
          tasks = value;
          print(tasks);
        });
      }
    );

  }

  Future insertIntoDatabase({
    required String title,
    required String date,
    required String time
  }
  ) async {
    return await database.transaction(
      (txn) {
        return txn.rawInsert(
          'INSERT INTO tasks (title, date, time, status) VALUES ("$title", "$date", "$timeController", "new")'
        ).then(
          (value) {
            print('$value inserted succsessfully');
          }
        ).catchError(
          (error){
            print('error inserting into table ${error.toString()}');
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }
  
  Future<List<Map>> getData(Database database) async {
    return await database.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM tasks');
  }
  
} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize

```
    late Database database;
```

in the StatefulWidget instead of it's State and in the createDatabase() call it like

```
    widget.database = await OpenDatabase...
```

Also try to see if adding await in initState helps.

Answer (score 0):

instead of
late Database database;

Write
static Database? database;